# How to validate whether a variable is valid integer allowing +/-? in pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to validate whether a input is a valid integer allowing for +/- entries.

I have tried this.

```
 function valid(elem)
 { 
      var num = parseInt(elem);
      if(!Number.isInteger(num))
      {
         alert ("Not an integer");
      }
 }
```

But the issue here is , it is validating even strings like `10sd` as an integer. So how to validate this?

I want to validate as following:

```
valid(-10) = true;
valid(+10) = true;
valid(-10.01) = false;
valid(10sd) = false;
valid(10.23see) = false;
valid(10) = true;
```

Comment: Is hexadecimal, octal or binary input valid? Depending on what you consider valid, a regular expression might be the simplest approach.

Comment: @NickParsons: That alone is not enough. `isNaN("5.5")` is `false`.

Comment: @FelixKling oh, I see. My bad

Comment: @FelixKling just plain numbers

Comment: With "plain numbers" I assume you mean decimal numbers. Is the input a string or a number? Do you want it to accept strings? (I assumed since you use `parseInt` but I'm not sure anymore; it's also unclear whether +/- just means positive or negative numbers or whether a string can start with + or -).

Comment: @FelixKling the input varies it can be string/number/decimal, i want to validate whether it is an integer. For ex. +10 and -10 is valid while 10sd or -10se aren't

Comment: You probably want `Number.isInteger(Number(elem))`, but note that a string `"0xa"` would be valid, since it's a valid hexadecimal number. Alternatively: `typeof elem !== 'number' && /^[+-]?\d+$/.test(elem) || Number.isInteger(elem)`

Comment: @FelixKling your answer works great and solves my issue. Thanks for your time. Can you please put is as an answer so that i can upvote?

Comment: No, since the question is closed as duplicate ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
function valid(value) {
   if(typeof value === 'number' && isFinite(value))
       alert ("It is an integer");
}
```

This function does the job, `typeof` is a keyword in Javascript which tells you the data type of the variable

You can check this out, for more usage of typeof:
https://webbjocke.com/javascript-check-data-types/

Edit: made a silly error in alert, it should alert if it is an integer, the if condition checks for number

Comment: `valid(5)` says "Not an integer".

Comment: Sorry for the error, answer updated

Answer (score 0):

Simple

```
function valid(elem){return parseInt(elem)==elem}
```

Comment: If you already know that a value is a number (`typeof elem=="number"`) why do you use `parseInt`? `parseInt` converts strings to numbers.

Comment: We need to determine if it is an integer. 
in fact, this is enough for this task, so the function can only be: function valid(elem){return parseInt(elem)==elem}

Comment: Then I would suggest `Math.floor(elem) === elem` instead. Of course the whole function can be replaced with `Number.isInteger` instead.